# 500 error when using sqlsrv_get_field on MSSQL smalldatetime

Tags: php, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm back again with more PHP problems, but this time with the DateTime class.

This is a section of my actual code:

```
//setup $dbc and $dbcOptions

function test($database, $databaseoptions, $termcode, $department)
{
  $tsql = "SELECT StartDate, StopDate 
           FROM CourseRecords 
           WHERE TermCode = '" .$termcode. "' AND Department = '" .$department. "';";
  $params = array();
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($database, $tsql, $params, $databaseoptions); //---Query ALL the things!!!

  if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo 'This page is broken<br />';
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }

  return $stmt;
}

$results = test($dbc, $dbcOptions, "142s", "CSC");

$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($results);
echo "rows = " .$rows;
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
{
    if(sqlsrv_fetch($results) !== false)
    {
      $startdate = date_format(sqlsrv_get_field($results, 0), "Y-m-d"); //line 72
      $stopdate = date_format(sqlsrv_get_field($results, 1), "Y-m-d");  //line 73
    }
}
```

I get the following errors in my `php-errors.log` file:

[13-Nov-2014 17:05:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  date_create(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for '-6.0/no DST' instead in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\directory\searchtest.php on line 72

[13-Nov-2014 17:05:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  date_create(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for '-6.0/no DST' instead in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\directory\searchtest.php on line 73

Creating `$startdate` and `$stopdate` as DateTime objects produces the same error when I do this:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago");
$startdate = new DateTime("2012-12-12", $timezone);
$stopdate = new DateTime("2012-12-12", $timezone);

// get $results and find $rows and junk

$startdate = sqlsrv_get_field($results, 0);
$stopdate = sqlsrv_get_field($results, 1);
```

which by all means should work because you guys have helped me with previous problems.

So my question is: Why does this fail with a 500 error and what can I do to correct it?

Comment: Try adding `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: @Latheesan That fixed it, I think. I'm going to test it some more and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into answer:

Try adding `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');` at the beginning of your script.